# Form submit not redirecting correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, submit

So I'm building a site on the WP platform and have never come across this before, hoping someone might be able to help me out.

I have a form, that when submitted is redirected to a sent / thank you page. I'm using the wp `home_url` function for the redirect. When I press submit, I'm getting a 404, but the url it's redirecting to is correct and there is a page published with that permalink.

To make it weirder, if I erase the permalink in the URL bar of my browser and retype it, exactly the same, it then finds the page no problem.

Here's the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>sent/" method="POST" class="col-md-7">
    <input id="name" placeholder="name:" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required></label>
    <input id="email" placeholder="email:" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" required> 
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="message:" name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" required></textarea>
    <button id="contact-submit" type="submit" class="btn form-control">Submit</button>
</form>
```

- NB I've tried using the actual URL instead of the wp `home_url` function as well, to no avail.

Just in case, here's the post commands too:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name, $email, \nMessage: $message";
$recipient = "email@email.com";
$subject = "Contact Form Submission";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

As always, thanks in advance for any help / insight!

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but everything to do with helping you.. Once you've figured out why your page isn't displaying correctly, you should read about [sanitizing your input for php email](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_secure_mail.asp), otherwise it's only a matter of time before you're the source of a lot of spam.

Comment: I don't actually see this doing any redirecting. Is the processing part of the form, [post commands] in the actual index file?

Comment: the form action directs to site.com/sent, that's where the form commands are. The form redirects to the correct URL, but for some reason it pulls a 404 instead of displaying the content on that page. If I go to the URL bar in my browser and just press enter, the page reloads and all the content is there, but of course, then the form details aren't sent to the email listed.

Comment: @EricBrockman I had similar problem when passing urls as parameters due to some settings in Apache. I've solved it by using urlencode() and urldecode() functions. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this problem is due to an issue with wordpress. Wordpress does not allow you to use the name="name" - this causes a 404 and the form values are not sent. I changes the name to 'form_name' and it works perfectly now.

Thanks for your help, hope this can help someone else too!

Thanks to Tom Elliot at http://www.webdevdoor.com for the help! http://www.webdevdoor.com/wordpress/submitting-form-wordpress-redirects-404-page/